# Proving maximum and minimum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

The maximum of two numbers $x$ and $y$ is represented by $\max(x,y)$. So $\max(-1,3)=\max(3,3)=3$ and $\max(-1,-4)=\max(-4,-1)=-1$. The minimum of $x$ and $y$ is represented by $\min(x,y)$. Can you help me to prove that
$$\max(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y+|y-x|}{2}$$
$$\min(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y-|y-x|}{2}$$

Comment: If $x>y$, evaluate the expressions on the right. If $x<y$, evaluate the expressions on the right. If both go through then the formula is correct.

Comment: Or, using symmetry, we can, without loss of generality, assume that $x>y$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{x+y+|y-x|}{2} &=
      \begin{cases}
        \frac{x+y+y-x}{2} & \text{if } y \geq x \\
        \frac{x+y-y+x}{2} & \text{if } y < x \\
      \end{cases}\\
&=    \begin{cases}
        \frac{2 \cdot y}{2} & \text{if } y \geq x \\
        \frac{2 \cdot x}{2} & \text{if } y < x \\
      \end{cases}\\
&=    \begin{cases}
        y & \text{if } y \geq x \\
        x & \text{if } y < x \\
      \end{cases}\\
&= \max(x,y)
\end{align}

Now you do the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that $x\leq y$. Then, $y-x\geq 0$, hence, $|y-x|=y-x$. Therefore,

$$
\frac{x+y+|y-x|}{2}=\frac{x+y+y-x}{2}=\frac{2y}{2}=y=\max\{x,y\}.
$$

This is one of four things you need to do. You must also consider the case $x>y$ above and then consider both $x\leq y$ and $x>y$ to prove the formula for the $\min$.